# Using COUNT() to get data from 3 joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, left-join

I have these 4 tables in MySql:

**User**:

- userID
- username
- password
- some other stuff

**Movie**:

- movieID
- name
- some other stuff

**Collection** (many-to-many relation between user and movie):

- userID
- movieID

**Review**:

- reviewID
- userID
- movieID
- some other stuff

So basically what I want is to pull data from user, review and collection and display some sort of user statistics, like **the number of reviews each user left, and the number of movies each user saved to their collection**. I thought it was just going to be a simple join between 3 tables but apparently I was wrong.

I thought using the COUNT() aggregate function would be the best idea and so I started by making separate queries for user-review and user-collection, and that works just fine, the result for both queries is correct.

```
 SELECT u.userID, username, COUNT(movieID) AS collection_size 
 FROM collection c INNER JOIN USER u ON u.userID=c.userID 
 GROUP BY c.userID


 userID username    collection_size
 7      user        2
 8      user03      6
```

And

```
SELECT u.userID, username, COUNT(movieID) AS review_count 
FROM review r INNER JOIN USER u ON u.userID=r.userID 
GROUP BY r.userID

userID  username    review_count
7       user        1
8       user03      4
10      user05      1
```

The problem arises when trying to join all three tables. The closest I've come to solving the issues is this:

```
SELECT u.userID, username, COUNT(DISTINCT c.movieID) AS collection_size, COUNT(DISTINCT r.movieID) AS review_count
FROM collection c INNER JOIN USER u ON u.userID=c.userID 
INNER JOIN review r ON r.userID=u.userID
GROUP BY u.userID

userID  username    collection_size review_count
7       user        2               1
8       user03      6               4
```

The result is almost correct, however as you can see the user with the userID of 10 is missing, even though he has left one review. This query seems to pick up only users which have left at least one review **AND** have at least one movie in their collection. I've verified this by adding a movie to user 10's collection. He then properly shows up in the result.
How do I change the query to show users who have left at least one review **OR** have at least one movie in their collection?

Basically I want the result to be this:

```
userID  username    collection_size review_count
7       user        2               1
8       user03      6               4
10      user05      0               1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this user does not have a collection (it is not returned by your first query). You can use `LEFT JOIN`s instead, starting from the user table:

```
SELECT u.userID, u.username, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.movieID) AS collection_size, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT r.movieID) AS review_count
FROM usr u 
LEFT JOIN collection c ON u.userID=c.userID 
LEFT JOIN review r ON r.userID=u.userID
GROUP BY u.userID
```

Although this works, it is not efficient. The joins multiply the rows on both sides, only to then count distinct primary key values. I think that the query would be more efficiently phrased with two subqueries for the counts:

```
select u.userid, u.username, 
    (select count(*) from collection c where c.userid = u.userid) as collection_size,
    (select count(*) from review     r where r.userid = u.userid) as review_count
from usr u
```

Comment: Using the left joins I still got the same result as the first time, but the restructured query did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a.userid
    ,b.qty_movies
    ,c.qty_reviews
FROM
    user a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT
        userid
        ,COUNT(*) qty_movies
      FROM
        collection
      GROUP BY 1
    ) b ON (a.userid = b.userid)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT
        userid
        ,COUNT(*) qty_reviews
      FROM
        review
      GROUP BY 1    
    ) c ON (a.userid = c.userid)
;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fiiwTyoFEuspGyscAh23bG/1